# Angular DomSanitizer not binding angular component

Tags: html, angular, dom

I am trying to add html content dynamically into a DIV. Statically this works nicely.

Code which works:

```
<popover-content #pop1
                 title="Cool Popover"
                 placement="right"
                 [closeOnClickOutside]="true">
  Popped up!!!
</popover-content>

<div>   
    <span>Testing with <span [popover]="pop1" [popoverOnHover]="true">popover</span> as they are not working with DomSanitizer</span>
</div>
```

Now I need to generate this div content in the backend and then have to dynamically add this inside the div.

Code  which doesn't work: 
**HTML:**

```
<popover-content #pop1
                     title="Cool PopOver"
                     placement="right"
                     [closeOnClickOutside]="true">
      Popped up!!!
    </popover-content>

    <div [innerHtml]="message | safeHtml">  
    </div>
```

**.ts file:**

```
this.message = '<span>Testing with <span [popover]="pop1" [popoverOnHover]="true">popover</span> as they are not working with DomSanitizer</span>'
```

**Pipe:**

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }

}
```

After this also the popover component was not getting called.

While inspecting, I did see that, for dynamically added `innerHtml` content to DIV, angular is not adding some special behavior to the tag attributes. Why so?
And how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `[innerHTML]="..."` you can add HTML to the DOM, but Angular won't care what HTML it contains, except for sanitization.

Angular components, directives, event and property bindings **only** work for HTML added statically to a components template.

What you can do is to compile the HTML with a components template at runtime like explained in [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular)