# ngModel fields in string will not render in dynamic component

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

So I asked this question a couple years ago with Ionic 3 and Angular 7. Got it solved and it also worked with Ionic 4 and Angular 8. But since upgrading to Angular 9, I cannot find a solution anywhere to make this work again.

The problem is that even tho the html renders correctly, the form fields will not render correctly. You can still see [(ngModel)]="answers.answer1" in inspect element. I setup a stackblitz on this and you can see the dynamic content being loaded in as well as a static input that is working properly.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-q7oeoz

Lastly: I 100% have to have the inputs inside the content and being loaded from JSON as a string. There are many Workbooks that have over thousand inputs spread out through the content. Static coding these with their countless sections outputted as single pages is not a solution for me.

Thanks for everyone's help!!

Comment: Really hoping someone at least has a general direction I can go.... I have done a lot of research and can't see to get it to work...

Comment: Hey Shane, Hope its not too late. Sorry for the delayed response. I will post my answer.